# How to open two file in compare mode in Arbortext Editor

Tags: xml, editor, compare

I Have two files for example   C:/testA/a.xml  and C:/testB/a.xml

These files content may be same or different

I need to write a .bat file which opens the compare result of both the above file.

I tried to Google but i don't find much resource on internet .

There is a Compare_files() method .

But i don't know exactly how to use this .

I tried in below way:

editor -c compare_files(\"testA/a.xml\", \"/testB/a.xml\")

But it dont work

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write an ACL script (see the Programmer's Guide). Also, your best place for getting answers about programming Arbortext is the Adepters Mailing List.

http://portal.ptcuser.org/p/fo/si/topic=21
You will need to create a login.

For more Arbortext resources: http://www.single-sourcing.com/company/social.html